# Sort Facebook Messenger contacts by idle time

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom, userscript, facebook

I wrote a UserScript that auto-sorts contacts by offline time using the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). I tried to make it as DRY as I could think, and I also tried to make my code as straight-forward as possible, commenting thoroughly. Please let me know any improvements I can make.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Facebook Messenger Chat Sorter
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Auto-sort contacts by offline time
// @author       Patrick Roberts
// @match        https://www.facebook.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict';

  // mutation observer to locate chat sidebar
  var exists = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    // if chat sidebar found in any mutations
    if (mutations.some(function(mutation) {
      // check if element with class is added
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        // return if any added element is the chat sidebar
        return Array.from(mutation.addedNodes).some(initFbChatSidebar);
      // check if class is changed in existing element
      } else {
        // return if changed element is the chat sidebar
        return initFbChatSidebar(mutation.target);
      }
    })) {
      // then de-initialize this observer
      exists.disconnect();
      exists.takeRecords();
    }
  });

  // start locating sidebar
  exists.observe(document.body, { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, attributeFilter: ['class'] });

  // returns if any element is the chat sidebar, and inits it
  function initFbChatSidebar(el) {
    if (el instanceof HTMLElement && el.classList.contains('fbChatSidebar')) {
      initChatSort(el.querySelector('ul'));

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  // initializes auto-sorting
  function initChatSort(ul) {
    var li = ul.children;

    // observer to sort contacts
    var observer = new MutationObserver(sort);

    // start sorting whenever list is mutated
    observer.observe(ul, { childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true });

    // also sort on initialization since list is already there
    sort();

    function sort() {
      // invoke native sorting algorithm
      Array.from(li).sort(function(la, lb) {
        // get offline times
        var a = getOfflineTime(la);
        var b = getOfflineTime(lb);

        // compare offline times
        return a - b;
      }).forEach(function(li) {
        // add list items to list in sorted order
        ul.appendChild(li);
      });

      // remove mutations from queue caused by sorting
      observer.takeRecords();
    }
  }

  // parse offline time from contact list item
  function getOfflineTime(li) {
    var str = li.querySelector('[class$="on"] [class$="-"]').textContent;
    var num, unit;

    num = +str.slice(0, -1);
    unit = str.slice(-1);

    // multiply time by 60 if hour
    if (unit === 'h') {
      num *= 60;
    // multiply time by 60 * 24 if day
    } else if (unit === 'd') {
      num *= 60 * 24;
    }

    return num;
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would suggest pulling up the functions. Though they get hoisted by JS, it's nice from a readability point of view that you know they exist first before code tries to use them.

---

```
// if chat sidebar found in any mutations
if (mutations.some(function(mutation) {
```

This is a huuuge `if` statement. You might want to consider pulling out that callback function. It doesn't use `mutations` anyways.

---

```
if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
    // return if any added element is the chat sidebar
    return Array.from(mutation.addedNodes).some(initFbChatSidebar);
  // check if class is changed in existing element
  } else {
    // return if changed element is the chat sidebar
    return initFbChatSidebar(mutation.target);
  }
```

Can be simplified into:

```
var isChildListMutation = mutation.type === 'childList';
return isChildListMutation  ? Array.from(mutation.addedNodes).some(initFbChatSidebar);
                            : initFbChatSidebar(mutation.target);
```

---

```
// start locating sidebar
exists.observe(document.body, { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, attributeFilter: ['class'] });
```

Consider breaking the config into newlines. As a single line, it isn't really readable.

---

```
  Array.from(li).sort(function(la, lb) {
    // get offline times
    var a = getOfflineTime(la);
    var b = getOfflineTime(lb);

    // compare offline times
    return a - b;
  }).forEach(function(li) {
    // add list items to list in sorted order
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });
```

Consider appending to a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) instead of directly to the DOM. Only after you append every `li` to the fragment, append the fragment to the `ul`.

---

```
var num, unit;

num = +str.slice(0, -1);
unit = str.slice(-1);
```

Consider putting `var` on the assignment operation instead. Save an extra line. Additionally, your `num` is not guarded against `NaN`.

Comment: I like almost all of your points except the one about the document fragment. Wouldn't that throw an error considering that they're already children of the `ul`?  calling `appendChild` with the argument being an element that already has a parent throws an error iirc, unless the parent that `appendChild` is invoked on, _is_ the parent of that child element already. In this specific case, it just moves it to the end like I'm already trying to do.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts *"calling appendChild with the argument being an element that already has a parent throws an error iirc"* - not really. https://jsfiddle.net/6zxqzwbx/

Comment: Fair enough.. I wonder why I thought that in the first place. I remember doing something a few years ago that somehow caused appendChild to throw an error. Very nice review, thank you for the effort.